# Can I give Zakat in the form of clothes?

Tags: practical-islam, zakat

It is a practice of many ladies to give away their clothes converting their value into Zakat. Please guide me in the following matter:

I have some new and slightly used stitched clothes which I am thinking to give them to needy families.

- Can I convert the value of clothes into Zakat?
- In this way can my Zakat will be paid off?

And if this sort of Zakat is acceptable, how do I determine the value? Do I have to arrange a buyer for my clothes to set the prices (market value) or can I set the price (will set prices even lower than market) by myself and convert it into Zakat?

Comment: Sell them yourself and pay off Zakat

Answer (score 1):

Allah says in verse92 in surat "Al-Imran":
{Never will you attain the good [reward] until you spend [in the way of Allah ] from that which you love. And whatever you spend - indeed, Allah is Knowing of it.}

These days, it is quite agreed upon among Muslim scholars that Zakat MUST be given as money. 
The only exception is when the recipient is in not capable of dealing with money wisely, such as a child, insane person or an addict ...etc, which does not seem to apply in your case. And even in the latter case, Zakat should be given in a form that is mostly needed by the recipient.
In summary, as Shoaib commented, the best way is to sell the cloths and pay off Zakat.

Comment: To add to this answer: O Believers, expend in Allah's Way the best portion of the wealth you have earned and of that We have produced for you from the earth, and **do not pick out for charity those worthless things which you yourselves would only accept in disdain by connivance, if they were offered to you**. Understand it well that Allah does not stand in need of anything whatsoever and has all the praise-worthy attributes. ([2:267](http://tanzil.net/#trans/en.maududi/2:267))